# Отправка сообщений программой от имени пользователя

Tags: api, telegram

Имеется пользователь в `Telegram` **Не бот!** Нужно от его имени с помощью программы выполнять определенные действия: получение сообщений, автоматическая отправка и т.д.

Какое `API` для этого использовать и возможно ли это вообще? `Telegram bot API` не подходит.

Comment: Через него работают клиенты Telegram, поэтому, [конечно](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getMessages), [можно](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage). Только API не для автоматической отправки, а для отправки - автоматической её делаете уже вы.

Comment: Можете дать какой-нибудь небольшой исходник, где есть отправка сообщений через Telegram API? (Желательно на Python)

Comment: Могу только предположить, что ответ будет где-то тут: [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), [Telepy](https://github.com/Surye/telepy). Не уверен, что исходник может быть небольшой :)